# ProGuard Retrace exactly outputs the stack trace itself

Tags: android, proguard, logcat

I did exactly what have been mentioned in here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html. And I signed the apk.

Here is the Log which has beed saved from LogCat window:

```
07-20 20:00:40.457: W/dalvikvm(4209): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410739a8)
07-20 20:00:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(4209): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 20:00:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(4209): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 20:00:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(4209):     at com.example.aproguardsample.b.a(Unknown Source)
07-20 20:00:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(4209):     at com.example.aproguardsample.a.onClick(Unknown Source)
07-20 20:00:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(4209):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
07-20 20:00:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(4209):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
07-20 20:00:40.461: E/AndroidRuntime(4209):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
```

But after executing this command (two times, with or without -verbose parameter):

```
retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt log.txt > out.txt
retrace.bat mapping.txt log.txt > out.txt
```

The file out.txt containing exactly same data as log.txt is created.

I don't know what am I doing wrong. I double tested the same procedure on another SDK and Eclipse versions, but the result is same.
Also note that the mapping file and log file are of same version.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve it. I downloaded the latest version of ProGuard from the SourceForge.com and it's retrace.bat just worked well :-)